# Order of elements to becounted in XSLT's 'count' function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have an instruction in my XSLT file which counts the  nodes and outputs a hyperlinked superscript number next to the word to which the note is attached, and also the note itself (with numbered hyperlink):

```
<xsl:template match="//tei:body//tei:note">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:text>footnoteref</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>#footnote</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <sup>
            <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>
        </sup>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:note" mode="footnote">
    <br>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:text>footnote</xsl:text>
                <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>#footnoteref</xsl:text>
                <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:number level="any" count="//tei:body//tei:note" format="1"/>.

        </a>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </i>
    </br>
</xsl:template>

[...]

<xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:body//tei:note" mode="footnote"/>
```

It all works fine. Nevertheless, I'd like to control the order in which the `<note>` elements get counted. For instance, if this is my .xml:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Bla<note>This is a second note</note> blabla</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Bla2<note>This is a first note</note> bla bla...</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'd like, as I say in the text, to output a '1' for the "This is a first note" note, and a '2' for the "This is a second note" note, even if in the .xml file they come in a different order.

In term of output, I am already outputting the text in the order I want with something like this at the beginning of my XSLT file:

```
<!-- Order of execution -->
<xsl:template match="tei:text/tei:body/tei:div">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:opener/tei:dateline"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:opener/tei:salute"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:p [not(tei:stamp)] [not(tei:address)] [not(tei:postscript)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:closer/tei:salute"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:closer/tei:signed"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:closer/tei:dateline"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:postscript"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:stamp"/>
</xsl:template>
```

with the result that the text is in the order I want it, and the note number go, for instance, from the top of the document, from 1 to 8, with a '9' between the '5' and the '6', because its corresponding note is in the tei:dateline).

How can I tell 'count' to count the `<note>` elements in the order I want, regardless from the order they appear in the XML file?

Comment: You haven't really explained how the value you want to output is to be determined, if you look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number you have various options but I am not sure which you need or is going to work for you,  if you want to count other elements than the `note` elements you can use a different pattern, if the `note` element has an attribute or text content you can use the `value` attribute of `xsl:number`, although I am not sure with your example with `first/second` to be meant to indicate the element has the number.

Comment: Perhaps you need to process the contents twice and only number once you have the result of the first transformation (in a variable).

Comment: Sorry @MartinHonnen, you're right, I forgot to add a piece of the xslt code (see my edited answer).

Comment: " if you want to count other elements than the note" -> No, I only want to count the `<note>` elements. I just want their reference number not to necessarily follow the order in which the `<note>` elements appear on the .xml file. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinHonnen: "I am not sure with your example with first/second to be meant to indicate the element has the number" -> no, they don't have a number, the footnote number is assigned automatically by the 'count' function.

Comment: So which order do you want if not the order in the input XML? As I said, there is an option with the `value` attribute, or as the specs formulates it, "The place marker to be formatted can either be supplied directly, in the `value` attribute, or it can be computed based on the position of a selected node within the tree that contains it". So if you process the input tree and use `xsl:number count`, you get a number based on the position in the input tree. If you first process the input into a different order and want a number based on the result, use an intermediary result in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a two-pass solution. Generate the output in the order you want in the first phase, then do the numbering in the second phase.

There are two ways of doing a two-pass transformation in XSLT: you can put the results of the first phase into a variable, then process the variable contents; or you can use two separate stylesheets. Which approach is best depends how closely-coupled you want the two passes to be.